# Sort column of hebrew strings alphabetically

Tags: excel, sorting, hebrew

Is there a way to sort a column of hebrew characters strings alphabetically in Excel (version 2013 here)? I have tried on my side with a list of very simple words, and it does not work (it does not produce any change in the order)

**EDIT:**

My client managed to sort the words on his side and suggested to use the context menu (below), which is not available on my side. I have a context button, which I added to the bar, but it did not sort out any helpful result.

[image]

When I pasted in the sorted worksheet, some layout in the whole document got messed up: for example now in some cells I see `(Right name (a` while the cell value is `Right name (a)'

I would say that there should be a way to sort left to right and right to left cell properties but I still haven't figured it out...

Comment: I copied some characters, then unsorted, resorted, and did not have any issues. Please provide more information.

Comment: I have a very simple list of words: מסעדת, פלאפל, קפה, בית

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step one**

Add Hebrew support, even if you don't have an Hebrew keyboard and don't plan to use one:

```
[If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7, before you can use any of the right-to-left features in Microsoft Office, or even correctly display right-to-left scripts, you must Add an input language and enable the keyboard layout for the right-to-left language.][1]
```

**Step two**

Add "context" to your ribbon bar (Excel Options -> Customize Ribbon). Without language support (step one), context will not work.